# What's the best way to write integration tests around carrierwave_backgrounder models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, integration-testing, carrierwave, sidekiq

I'm trying to write integration tests around a Rails model that uploads a document in the background. I'm using the [carrierwave_backgrounder](https://github.com/lardawge/carrierwave_backgrounder) gem as well as [sidekiq](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq). The code itself is all up and running as expected, but I'm having trouble figuring out how best write integration tests around it. I've tried adding `require 'sidekiq/testing/inline'` within my `spec_helper` file, but the uploaded document is still turning out nil in the next step after saving the model. I can stub out the stuff around it, but it seems like best practice is not to do that in integration specs. It would be nice to be able to test the behavior while the file is still uploading and afterwards as well. Any suggestions on how best to handle this?